# Direct proof that the product of odd integers is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

> Prove $P(x,y)$: If $x$ and $y$ are odd integers, then the product  $xy$ must also be odd.

I need a direct proof of this.

I know that $ x $ and $y$ both have to equal to $2n+1$ in order for them to be odd. But that's all I have. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Any odd number can be written as $2n-1$, for some integer $n$. Then, consider:
$$(2n-1)(2m-1)=4mn-2(m+n)+1$$
$4mn-2(m+n)$ is even for all $m,n$, implying that...

Comment: Why did you use $m$ instead of another $n$?

Comment: @rubito Because we're multiplying two different odd numbers, not the same one.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\, $ Multiplying by an odd $ $ *preserves parity:* $\ (1\!+\!2k)\,n = n + 2(kn)\,$ has same parity as $\,n.$

Comment: Said  $\!\bmod 2\!:\  {\rm odd}\ \color{#c00}x = 1\!+\!2k\equiv \color{#c00}1\Rightarrow \color{#c00}xn\equiv \color{#c00}1n\equiv n\,$ by the [congruence product rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). By induction the same is true for $x$ any product of $k$ odds, by $\,\color{#c00}1^k\equiv 1\ \ $